# incorrect content image with autolayout 3 uibutton same width proportionaly to width screen

Tags: ios, uibutton, interface-builder, aspect-ratio, ios-autolayout

I have 3 buttons which is have same width proportionally to width screen,
and no constraint error,

(=leadingsuperview)button1(=HSpace)button2(=HSpace)button3(=trailingsuperview)

button2 same width to button 1

button3 same width to button 1

button1 center vertical to superview

button 2 and 3 center vertical to button 1

button1 height is proportional to its width 1:1 ratio

button2 and 3 is equal to height button1

**Result:**

3 buttons has correct frame (i know why it correct because i set background color to yellow and its true have same width)

but the incorrect part is, why just the 1st button images is smaller, the others button have correct size images.

already set at interfacebuilder like below:

```
[btn setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentFill];
[btn setContentVerticalAlignment:UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentFill];
```

3 buttons have the same property,

but why just 1st button has incorrect images content, like it has been aspect fit for some reason (i didn't set aspect fit or whatsoever).

for more detail see these pictures below:

**at interface-builder:**

[image]

**at compiled device:**

[image]

Anybody has experienced this?

ps: for iOS >=8.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution:

It is because I have custom class property that build in the runtime of interface builder.

I forgot to remove the 1st button custom property, that explain why only 1st button is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You may have used the UIButton's `image` property and not the `backgroundImage` unlike the other buttons. You can set the `backgroundImage` by code like this;

`[button setBackgroundImage:anImage forState:UIControlStateNormal]`

alternatively, you can set it on the storyboard using the UIButton's File Inspector.

Comment: all is using UIButton's `image` property not `backgroundImage`, but i want to use the image's property not background image property for some reason.

Comment: or should I use `backgroundImage` for this kind of cases? I try your solution using `backgroundImages` property and it shows correct content images.

Comment: awesome. *thumbsup

Answer (score 1):

I think the Stack View will do better in this case.

at interface-builder:

[image]

at attributes inspector:

[image]

button1 height is proportional to its width 1:1 ratio
button2 and button3 hasn't any constraint

hope this can help you :)

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention that this is for iOS >= 8.4,

Comment: `UIStackView` is for iOS >=9.0,
will edit the description.

Comment: @YosephWijaya Do you have gmail? I wrote a demo based on your description, but the buttons shows correctly.

Comment: hmm, really? yeah sure, mail me at info@yoseph.ws

Comment: I have sent it to you.

Comment: yeah It 100% correct at your project demo, again the logic is correct but when i implement on the original interface builder it seems not correct, i will try to debug more.